# Is it possible to define an inner product to an arbitrary field?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I've been trying to find the most general definition of an inner product space.

Every definition I've found is either to $\mathbb{R}$ or to $\mathbb{C}$.
Is it possible to define an inner product to an arbitrary field?
In other words, is there a more general way of formulating the conjugate symmetry property?

EDIT:
It would have to be an ordered field to have positive definiteness make sense, I guess.

Comment: Essentially the same question was asked on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6701/definition-of-inner-product-for-vector-spaces-over-arbitrary-fields