definition of dot product with respect to underlying field
Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a vector space on some field $\mathbb{K}$.
Most often, when we want to give it a dot product it is in the form of a bilinear definite positive, symmetric application $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{X}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$.
But if $\mathbb{K}$ is $\mathbb{C}$, the definition changes to hermitian, sesquilinear and the positivity should be changed from $\langle x|x \rangle \geq0$ to $\langle x|x \rangle\in\mathbb{R}^+$ (which I never saw expressed like this, the comparison to $0$ was always implicitly considered valid).
Is there a more generic definition that encompass all possible $\mathbb{K}$, possibly with adding somme requirements to $\mathbb{K}$ (that seems necessary in order to define positivity)?
Besides, must the output be in the same field that the one upon which is defined $\mathcal{X}$?
IMHO, the right idea is "inner product" but the definitions I can find do not answers the questions above and seem even wrong with respect to the type of symmetry.
Note: closest questions I found are:

Problem with the Definition of Inner Product Space.
Defining a generalised version of inner product over $*$-fields
What properties must a field $K$ satisfy in order to define an inner product on a $K\!$-vector space?

But their answers are not complete enough (though the third one introduced the idea of using an involution):

how does positivity generalized
how to derive a norm, have Pythagore and Cauchy-Schwartz
is the product $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{X}\mapsto\mathbb{K}$ or can we switch to $\mathbb{K'}$


This was linked in one of your links. I think they make some important observations, and I agree with the idea that an "inner product" ought to be an anisotropic quadratic form. Obviously that doesn't work directly for $\mathbb C$, so I would suggest maybe that an "inner product" on a $K$-vector space $V$ consists of an involution $$ on $K$ and a $$-sesquilinear form on $V$ which is anisotropic when considered as a symmetric $L$-bilinear form, where $L$ is the fixed field of $*$.

Please specify exactly what is missing in the links you have. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625701/what-properties-must-a-field-k-satisfy-in-order-to-define-an-inner-product-on seems to be a 100% duplicate for example. "Answers are not complete enough" is not specific and won't help potential answerers to address your problem.

Does this answer your question? Option 1 is what I suggested, and they give lots of references.

@NicholasTodoroff this is interesting but without full access to the document I cannot check some claims. For instance, the fact that Cauchy-Schwarz is till valid, seems to rely on additional axioms. (looking to a few proofs, that relies on polynomial expressions, I think that it restricts the possibilities on the output space of the inner product). Also what is <lx|y> (l*<x|y>? if (lx) is lx for the automorphism).  How to derive a norm? Sorry, not much place to expose my concerns.

@Oersted Yes, you're right, that's quite a glaring oversight by the author of the answer. I had a look at the book, $K$ is assumed to be a "complete non-Archimedean valued field with nontrivial valuation". This means $K$ is equipped with a nontrivial valuation that induces an ultrametric which is complete. I have no idea what you mean by "what is $\langle lx|y\rangle$?"

@NicholasTodoroff not easy to express these subjects in comments. ⟨lx|y⟩ was about how linearity or sesquilinearity can be expressed in a generalised way. For instance an involution f(lx) can give g(l)f(x) where g(l) is also an involution on K?

Sesquilinearity is (1) linear in one argument (let's say second)$$\langle x,ay+by'\rangle=a\langle x,y\rangle+b\langle x,y'\rangle;$$(2) conjugate symmetry$$\langle x,y\rangle=\langle y,x\rangle^.$$These together imply conjugate linearity in the first argument,$$\langle ax+bx',y\rangle=\langle y,ax+bx'\rangle^=a^\langle y,x\rangle^+b^\langle y,x'\rangle^=a^\langle x,y\rangle+b^\langle x',y\rangle.$$I was confused because your question came out of nowhere.
